# How to handle django returning Nonetype has no len()

Tags: python, html, django

I'm getting this `Nonetype` error. I'm stuck at it all day.
First i was getting `MultiDictError` after changing it to

```
 filetitle = request.POST.get('bob')
   contentitle =  request.POST.get('pop')
```

It seems to work and now this error.

views.py:

```
def add(request):
   filetitle = request.POST.get('bob')
   contentitle =  request.POST.get('pop')

   return render(request, "add/add.html"),{
          "entries":util.save_entry(filetitle,contentitle)

    }
```

utills.py

```
def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """

    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))
```

add.html

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>Create New Page</h1>
    <form  action="encyclopedia:add" method="post">
       {%csrf_token%}
       <input name="bob" type="text" placeholder="Enter the Markdown content " id="abz">
       <textarea name="pop" rows="20" cols="25" value="content"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**error**:

```
Internal Server Error: /add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/knox/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/knox/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/knox/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/knox/django/wiki/encyclopedia/views.py", line 44, in add
    "entries":util.save_entry(filetitle,contentitle)
  File "/home/knox/django/wiki/encyclopedia/util.py", line 28, in save_entry
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))
  File "/home/knox/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 128, in __init__
    self.size = len(content)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I tried several things but none of them seems to work.
I think as form is still empty it returns none and django doesnt know how to solve it.
please dont delete my post as im new to stackoverflow i might not be familier wit practices.

Comment: Probably either `filetitle` or `contentitle` might be `None`

Comment: yeah  hose are yet to be populated by form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it sucessfully as the form was empty it was returning **None**.
Simple **If else statement** solved the problem.
This is what i did,
**views.py:**

```
def add(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    filetitle = request.POST.get('bob')
    contentitle =  request.POST.get('pop')
    if filetitile and contentitle:
     
      return render(request, "add/add.html",{
         "entries":util.save_entry(filetitle,contentitle)
           })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `save_entry` function check if `content` is `None` before doing anything else. If it is `None` you can't actually save it and your function should return.

But I think there might be a deeper problem in your design if you call the `add` function with an empty form. Usually, this is what is done:

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WhateverForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            context = { 'form': form, }
            return render(request, 'whatever-on-success.html', context)
    else:
        form = WhateverForm()

    context = { 'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'whatever.html', context)
```

Comment: Yes but has im not using **django forms**,Im not able to use `is_valid` and `cleaned_data ` methods. Is there any alternative to this without using django form?

Comment: is there any good reason not to use a Django form? (it's probably a very stupid comment...)

Comment: I don't think Django form is that friendly when it comes to bounded data. I find easy to use htnl form. You don't have to be smarty. I just asked for alternative.